# Looping in Javascript, multiple variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, for-loop

I have a MySQL database from which I fetch data to show a marker on my Google map. I would want to show n markers but I don't know how to implement for-loop so that

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: myLatlng,
map: map,
title: 'Hello World!',
});
```

would repeat n-times. I've tried adding for loop function but I can't get it right. I'm only starting to learn JavaScript.

**Here's the rest of the code: http://jsfiddle.net/Wkn9v/7/**

Thank you!

Comment: Where is your `myLatlng` defined?

Comment: It's always best to include *what didn't work* so the answers can help explain what you were doing wrong. Otherwise, it's just "oh you could it this way, or that way", but it may not be any clearer to you in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified your code so the logic is performed in the initialize function, because otherwise the loop wasn't executing properly. There was some other stuff in the wrong places too. This works:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
  var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');

  $.getJSON('http://www.wawhost.com/appProject/fetchmarker.php?callback=?', function (data) {
    initialize(data);
  });

  function initialize(data) {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882, 131.044922),
      mapOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      },
      map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, mapOptions),
      pos, lat, lng, latlang, marker;

    for (var i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; i++) {
      localStorage.loc = data[i].location;

      pos = localStorage.loc.split(",");
      lat = parseFloat(pos[0]);
      lng = parseFloat(pos[1]);

      latlang = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlang,
        map: map,
        title: 'Hello World!' // <<< Keep in mind that trailing , that was here is unnecessary
      });
    }
  }

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/Wkn9v/13/

Comment: Martin, I made some enhancements to code. If you disagree, feel free to revert, but @alesko007, I demonstrate in the edited code at http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/Wkn9v/13/ ways in which to scope variables, use a reference for `data.length` in the loop so `data.length` isn't recalculated each iteration (and thus a performance hit on longs lists), and fixed the trailing `,` on your object literals (I was bit hard by the *trailing comma of death* some time ago and I'm still in recovery, most browsers except IE6 don't care). I was interesting to see it in action.

Comment: All good! Happy to help.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Thanks for that, it was a bit messy how I formatted it. Changes are sweet, and thanks for linking it up to jsfiddle too.

Comment: One thing that I did want to demonstrate was the scope reference to `document.getElementById('map_canvas')`. `getElementById` *is* fast, but it's best to cache it in or above the calling scope, especially if there's 1000 data points to plot or whatever.

Comment: That is a very good point.

Answer (score 3):

What did you try? A for loop works fine http://jsfiddle.net/Wkn9v/3/

```
for(var i=0; i < 3; i++) {
      var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882 + i/2, 131.044922);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatlng,
          map: map,
          title: 'Hello World!',
      });
}
```

Maybe you're using the same lat/long in your loop? If so, they're on top of each other, and it looks like a single marker?

Comment: Not seeing the OPs `for` loop "attempt" kinda makes it hard to figure out why it wasn't working. I think we're just demonstrating a `for` loop works. Meh.

Comment: That's why I told the OP to post their code, and guessed what could have been wrong with it. The OP's code already has a for loop, so they can at least use it.

Comment: I wasn't being critical, just a little perturbed at the way the question was asked. Looks like we both sorta went on the track anyhow. Oh well. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list to run through, and you don't need the list you're working with but to setup the `markers` or whatnot, you can use a queue-based method that iterates over the list until the list is empty:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  (function initialize() {
    var pos = localStorage.loc.split(","),
      lat = parseFloat(pos[0]),
      lng = parseFloat(pos[1]),
      myLatlngs = [
        new google.maps.LatLng(-25.0, 131.0),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-26.0, 132.0),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-24.0, 130.0)
      ],
      myLatlngs,
      mapOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: myLatlngs[0],
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      },
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

    while (myLatlng = myLatlngs.shift()) {
      new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title: 'Hello World!'
      });
    }
  })();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/Wkn9v/9/

By "list" here I'm referring to an `array`, not an `object`s properties. So assume you get something the following back from your fetch script:

```
data = [
  {"id":"1","published":"yes","location":"-25.363882,131.044922"},
  {"id":"2","published":"yes","location":" -24.96614015991296, 139.7900390625"},
  {"id":"3","published":"yes","location":"-28.76765910569124, 128.3203125"}
];

while (localStorage.loc = data.shift()) {
  pos = localStorage.loc.location.split(",");
  lat = parseFloat(pos[0]);
  lng = parseFloat(pos[1]);

  latlang = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlang,
    map: map,
    title: 'Hello World!'
  });
}
```

I'm not real sure what you're up to with `localStorage.loc` here, since you overwrite it each time. If you omit it, you could possible set [`while (pos = ...location.split(','))`](http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/Wkn9v/16/) instead. Just depends on what you're doing and how the `data` is being interacted with in your script.

Comment: Why modify the array just to iterate over it? Unnecessary work that makes the code harder to read, specially when the OP is asking about for loops

Comment: @JuanMendes - Why modify the array just to iterate over it...? You mean the array I created to demonstrate a queue? Especially since the accepted answer shows `data` being something like a queue, I think it's relevant (which I note in the text in the answer). I just think `while` is often less verbose, more directly representative, or faster (in some cases), so I like to show it as an option.

Comment: In this case, it's surely slow because `shift` has to update the indices on every element in the array. I just think if you don't need to modify the state of something, you shouldn't, makes it less likely to require changes in the future. I don't see how this is a `queue`, you're never pushing something onto it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for` loop like this:

```
var myLatlng = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(-10.0, 10.0),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-10.2, 10.0),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-10.0, 10.2)
    ];

var marker;

for(var i = 0; i < myLatlng.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng[i],
        map: map,
        title: 'Hello World!',
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need to do: http://jsfiddle.net/Wkn9v/10/

The code is pretty simple:

```
function initialize(data) {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882, 131.044922),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    zoom: 4
  });

  var length = data.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    var loc = data[i].location;
    var pos = loc.split(",");
    var lat = +pos[0];
    var lng = +pos[1];

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
      map: map
    });
  }
}
```

Here's what it does:

1. Creates a map centered at a fixed location.
2. For each location fetched via AJAX it creates a new marker.